# some error in a code for prime factorisation

Tags: python-3.x, prime-factoring

I am a beginner. Here I need a solution for finding prime factors of a particular number. I know there are many better ways available but knowing my mistake is important right now. please help!

```
list1 = [] 
def primes_till (num):
    
    for digit in range(3,num):
        for dividend in range(2,digit):
            if digit%dividend == 0:
                prime = False
                break
            else:
                prime = True
        if prime :
            list1.append(digit)
            
    return list1   #this function is for finding all primes that occur till a particular no.


def prod(any_list):
    product = 1
    for item in any_list:
        product = product* item
    return product   #a function for mutiplying all the elements in a list



def func(num):    
    new_list = [1]
    list2 = primes_till(num)
    
    
    while prod(new_list) != num:
    
        for prime in list2:

            if num%prime == 0:
                new_list.append(prime)
                num = num/prime
            else:
                list2.remove(prime)
    
    return new_list   #to get the final list of prime factors of a number
            
func(15)
```

Comment: Please identify what this code is doing wrong.

Comment: It doesn't give any output. And I have to eventually interrupt the kernel

Comment: Then you should try using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Once `list2` in `func` becomes empty, the `while` loop never terminates.

Comment: Yes, I got my mistake. Thank you!